# Symbol of setter declaration

Tags: dart

Is it actually possible to write a setter Symbol without calling the Symbol constructor? because the setter Symbol contains an `=` sign , so `#x=` does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as far as I know.

Related issues: http://dartbug.com/13640, http://dartbug.com/10029

Comment: You *can* do ugly stuff with noSuchMethod to capture the assignment `memberName`, but then it's simpler to just use `const Symbol("x=")`, and it helps dart2js know that the symbol is being used.